# Compare MD5 hash with different file paths

Tags: md5, checksum, md5sum

I downloaded some large files and their accompanying md5sum checksum from a database. I then wanted to use md5sum with the -c flag to check the integrity of the downloaded files. However, the file name listed in the .md5 files contain just the file name, whereas when I list the files on the command line after the -c flag they include the full directory path on my computer. Because of this, md5sum produces an error saying it can't find the files. Is there any way to tell md5sum to ignore the directory path and focus just on the filename? I'm running centos-release-6-6.el6.centos.12.2.x86_64

Comment: Do you mind sharing with us what "md5" you're referring to? Or at least the OS?

Comment: @HannoBinder Apologies, I have updated my question.